# Returning rows based on the count(value) = 1

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query similar to this:

```
select
    clm.CLM_ID,
    csv.CSV_PRC_CD
FROM
    CLM_CLAIM clm inner join CSV_CLM_SRV csv on clm.CLM_iD = csv.CSV_CLM_ID
GROUP BY
    clm.CLM_ID,
    csv.CSV_PRC_CD
```

My results look something like this:

```
CLM_ID      CSV_PRC_CD     
----------- ---------------
       5087 0270           
       5087 0305           
       5087 0351           
       5087 0637           
       5087 0730           
     365294 99221          
     406116 0250           
     406116 0300           
     406116 0450           
     523504 99202          
     602677 73080          
     602677 73100          
     901343 97002          
     901343 97014          
    1040368 00190          
    1250851 93306
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to return only the rows that have only ONE CSV_PRC_CD associated with a CLM_ID. So my results should look like:

CLM_ID      CSV_PRC_CD

---

```
 365294 99221          
 523504 99202          
1040368 00190          
1250851 93306
```

Anything where the `CLM_ID` has more than 1 `CSV_PRC_CD` associated with it should be omitted from my results.

Comment: tsql or db2? which is it?

Comment: db2. tags have been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest query is:

```
select clm.CLM_ID, MIN(csv.CSV_PRC_CD) as CSV_PRC_CD
FROM CLM_CLAIM clm inner join CSV_CLM_SRV csv on clm.CLM_iD = csv.CSV_CLM_ID
GROUP BY clm.CLM_ID
having COUNT(distinct csv.CSV_PRC_CD) = 1
```

This can be made slightly more efficient by using the following `having` clause instead:

```
having min(csv.CSV_PRC_CD) = max(csv.CSV_PRC_CD)
```

`count(distinct)` is typically a bit more resource intensive than `min()` and `max()`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is joining on itself using `COUNT(*) = 1`:

```
SELECT
    clm.CLM_ID,
    csv.CSV_PRC_CD
FROM
    CLM_CLAIM clm 
        INNER JOIN CSV_CLM_SRV csv on clm.CLM_iD = csv.CSV_CLM_ID
        INNER JOIN (
               SELECT CSV_CLM_ID
               FROM CSV_CLM_SRV 
               GROUP BY CSV_CLM_ID 
               HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 ) T
          ON T.CSV_CLM_ID = csv.CSV_CLM_ID
```

I don't think you need to keep the GROUP BY any longer, but if you have multiple records in your Claim table, then you can add it back.